# ubuntu 14.04 lts upgrade to xenial xerus

Tags: 14.04

Please help me I was updating my ubuntu 14.04 lts to ubuntu 16.04.3 xenial xerus but when I restarted it, it became grub. It says : GNU Grub version 2.02~beta2-ubuntu1.14

*Ubuntu (when i click this i becomes like a black and white thing with words)
Advanced options for Ubuntu (it has 8 programs. 4 are recvery mode and nothing works)

Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69406/discussion-on-question-by-cytnix-ubuntu-14-04-lts-upgrade-to-xenial-xerus).

Comment: If you know about running Ubuntu with the Gigabyte GA-F2A68HM-S1 motherboard, please chip in and help solve the problem of Cytnix.